# .net Compact Framework callstack - how?

Tags: compact-framework, stack-trace

The `System.Diagnostics` namespace (and `GetFrame(int frameNumber)` in particular) is not available in the CF. How do I go about getting callstack details when running on CE (6.0 R3) ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you throw an exception you can then look at the callstack in the exception by parsing the callstack string.  There really aren't any cleaner alternatives.

Comment: Thanks, I have been a googling and it seems folks concur.